# Results from a query not being preserved throughout web page

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript, ado

I am very new to VB, and was asked to look at a problem with values not populating a drop down menu. The code below populates the first drop down menu, but the second drop down menu is blank. If I copy and paste the sql execute to recreate the `rs` variable, my drop down menus will populate.

I'm sure I'm not preserving the variable correctly, but like I said, I am very new to VB.

```
<%    
     sql = ""    
     sql = sql & "EXECUTE dbo.web_FetchPlans @ID = " & ID    
     Set rs = objConn.execute(sql)    
%>

<select name="first" type="text" ">    
   <option value="">Please select ...</option>

    <%   if not rs.eof then
          rs.moveFirst()
          do while not rs.EOF
    %>

<%

if not rs.eof then    
    rs.moveFirst()    
    do while not rs.EOF
%>

<option value="<%=rs("productCode")%>"><%=rs("productName")%></option>

<%
rs.moveNext()  
loop
  end if    
%> 


 </select>
```

So when I go to create my second drop down box using the same code, to loop through `rs`, my options are empty.

Comment: Please format your code by indenting it with four spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem may lie in this code -

```
<%   if not rs.eof then
      rs.moveFirst()
```

By the time you reach your second drop down list the `rs.EOF` condition will be true so the `rs.moveFirst()` won't occur and the loop will end immediately.